# JSON "POST" to Flask View doesn't work

Tags: jquery, python, json, post, flask

I want to send some JSON via POST to my Flask View.

here is my code

js:

```
$.post('/blog/add/ajax',
  { "title": "hallo", "article": "test" },
  function(data) {
    console.log(data.title);
    console.log(data.article);
  },
  "json"
);
```

py:

```
@app.route('/blog/add/ajax', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def add_blog_ajax():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.json['title']
        article = request.json['article']
        blog = Blog(title, article)
        db.session.add(blog)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(title=title, article=article)
```

error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

i dont know what to do, and whats going wrong here.

Comment: Based on the error, I would suggest that request.json is not properly filled out.  Can you output the `request.body` and headers.  Maybe you aren't sending the appropriate content type.

Comment: Does the `request.body` have content?

Comment: @sberry jup there is content

Comment: That means the content-type is not triggering the update of json.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok I got a solution:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "/blog/add/ajax",
  data: JSON.stringify({title: 'hallo', article: 'test'}),
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.title);
    console.log(data.article);
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

This works for me now!

Comment: Note the `contentType` was specified.

Comment: one slight shortcut is to use `JSON.stringify` on the object you want to pass as `data`.  So your data parameter would be equal to `JSON.stringify({title: 'hallo', article: 'test'})`